# VMware tools installed but not working

Tags: kali-linux, vmware

I've successfully installed `VMwareTools-10.0.5-3228253.tar.gz`on Kali Linux rolling release 2016.1 using this guide:

https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-patches

1. put `VMwareTools-10.0.5-3228253.tar.gz` in a folder on desktop named "new"
2. on a terminal run this `git clone https://github.com/rasa/vmware-tools-
   patches.git`
3. copy the contents of the `vmware-tools-patches`folder in the "new" folder on desktop
4. open a terminal in "new" folder and run this command `./untar-and-patch-and-compile.sh`
5. after it's done on the same terminal run this `./compile.sh`
6. extract `VMwareTools-10.0.5-3228253.tar.gz` into another folder and open a terminal in that folder and run `./vmware-install.pl`
7. restart the VM

before that I run `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y` to make sure everything is updated and installed headers using `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`.
I tried lots of time installing it and after the first install it had to uninstall it first in order to reinstall it but I don't think it can cause this issue, I'm not sure though. I can't copy any file to/from Windows 10 host to Kali Linux VM using drag & drop, neither can copy/paste texts etc.

here are the services currently running in my Guest VM (VMware workstation 12.1)

```
root@kali:~# lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
nls_utf8               16384  1
isofs                  40960  1
udf                    90112  0
crc_itu_t              16384  1 udf
bnep                   20480  2
vmw_vsock_vmci_transport    28672  0
vsock                  36864  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
fuse                   94208  9
nfnetlink_queue        20480  0
nfnetlink_log          20480  0
nfnetlink              16384  2 nfnetlink_log,nfnetlink_queue
bluetooth             512000  5 bnep
rfkill                 24576  4 bluetooth
binfmt_misc            20480  1
snd_ens1371            28672  4
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_ens1371
snd_seq_device         16384  1 snd_rawmidi
snd_ac97_codec        126976  1 snd_ens1371
snd_pcm               102400  2 snd_ac97_codec,snd_ens1371
snd_timer              32768  1 snd_pcm
snd                    81920  14          snd_ac97_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_ens1371,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
iosf_mbi               16384  0
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_ac97_codec
evdev                  20480  6
ppdev                  20480  0
psmouse               126976  0
pcspkr                 16384  0
gameport               16384  1 snd_ens1371
serio_raw              16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
vmw_balloon            16384  0
sg                     32768  0
parport_pc             28672  0
parport                49152  2 ppdev,parport_pc
vmwgfx                233472  3
ttm                    94208  1 vmwgfx
8250_fintek            16384  0
nfit                   32768  0
battery                16384  0
drm_kms_helper        131072  1 vmwgfx
drm                   348160  6 ttm,drm_kms_helper,vmwgfx
vmw_vmci               65536  1 vmw_vsock_vmci_transport
shpchp                 36864  0
acpi_cpufreq           20480  0
i2c_piix4              24576  0
processor              36864  1 acpi_cpufreq
ac                     16384  0
button                 16384  0
autofs4                40960  2
ext4                  577536  1
crc16                  16384  2 ext4,bluetooth
mbcache                20480  1 ext4
jbd2                  106496  1 ext4
vmw_pvscsi             24576  0
vmxnet3                53248  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
sd_mod                 40960  3
sr_mod                 24576  1
cdrom                  57344  1 sr_mod
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ata_generic            16384  0
crc32c_intel           24576  0
jitterentropy_rng      16384  0
sha256_ssse3           28672  1
sha256_generic         24576  1 sha256_ssse3
hmac                   16384  1
drbg                   24576  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  2 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
mptspi                 24576  2
scsi_transport_spi     32768  1 mptspi
uhci_hcd               45056  0
ehci_pci               16384  0
ata_piix               36864  1
ehci_hcd               77824  1 ehci_pci
mptscsih               32768  1 mptspi
libata                233472  2 ata_generic,ata_piix
mptbase                77824  2 mptspi,mptscsih
usbcore               233472  4 uhci_hcd,ehci_hcd,ehci_pci,usbhid
e1000                 135168  0
usb_common             16384  1 usbcore
scsi_mod              229376  8     sg,scsi_transport_spi,libata,mptspi,vmw_pvscsi,sd_mod,sr_mod,mptscsih
```

**UPDATE** the output when I run `apt-get install open-vm-tools`, still didn't make any difference.

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install open-vm-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
libxerces-c3.1 libxml-security-c17v5
Suggested packages:
open-vm-tools-desktop
The following NEW packages will be installed:
libxerces-c3.1 libxml-security-c17v5 open-vm-tools
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,644 kB of archives.
After this operation, 6,918 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64     libxerces-c3.1 amd64 3.1.2+debian-1 [851 kB]
Get:2 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64   libxml-security-c17v5 amd64 1.7.3-1 [265 kB]                
Get:3 http://kali.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/kali kali-rolling/main amd64   open-vm-tools amd64 2:10.0.5-3227872-2 [528 kB]             
Fetched 1,644 kB in 2min 24s (11.4 kB/s)                                                                                          
Selecting previously unselected package libxerces-c3.1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 310318 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libxerces-c3.1_3.1.2+debian-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxerces-c3.1:amd64 (3.1.2+debian-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxml-security-c17v5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxml-security-c17v5_1.7.3-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxml-security-c17v5:amd64 (1.7.3-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package open-vm-tools.
Preparing to unpack .../open-vm-tools_2%3a10.0.5-3227872-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking open-vm-tools (2:10.0.5-3227872-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-6) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (228-4) ...
Setting up libxerces-c3.1:amd64 (3.1.2+debian-1) ...
Setting up libxml-security-c17v5:amd64 (1.7.3-1) ...
Setting up open-vm-tools (2:10.0.5-3227872-2) ...

Configuration file '/etc/vmware-tools/poweroff-vm-default'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
  The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** poweroff-vm-default (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
 Installing new version of config file /etc/vmware-tools/poweroff- vm-default ...

Configuration file '/etc/vmware-tools/poweron-vm-default'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
  The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** poweron-vm-default (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
 Installing new version of config file /etc/vmware-tools/poweron-  vm-default ...

Configuration file '/etc/vmware-tools/resume-vm-default'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** resume-vm-default (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
 Installing new version of config file /etc/vmware-tools/resume-vm-default ...

Configuration file '/etc/vmware-tools/scripts/vmware/network'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** network (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
 Installing new version of config file /etc/vmware-tools/scripts/vmware /network ...

Configuration file '/etc/vmware-tools/statechange.subr'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** statechange.subr (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
 Installing new version of config file /etc/vmware-tools/statechange.subr ...

Configuration file '/etc/vmware-tools/suspend-vm-default'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** suspend-vm-default (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
 Installing new version of config file /etc/vmware-tools/suspend-vm-default ...

Configuration file '/etc/vmware-tools/vgauth.conf'
==> File on system created by you or by a script.
==> File also in package provided by package maintainer.
What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
  D     : show the differences between the versions
  Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
 *** vgauth.conf (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ? y
Installing new version of config file /etc/vmware-tools/vgauth.conf ...
update-rc.d: We have no instructions for the open-vm-tools init script.
update-rc.d: It looks like a non-network service, we enable it.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-6) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (228-4) ...
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: Reinstalling the vm-tools did not help me in this situation, but running the reset script provided by the Kali team did. I would post the script as an answer but dont have the rep for it. Its here; https://docs.kali.org/general-use/install-vmware-tools-kali-guest

Answer (score 1):

if you have `open-vm-tools` installed remove it first, then try:

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev
sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools-desktop fuse
```

this got me up and running, using kali

```
user@user:~$ uname -r
4.6.0-kali1-amd64
user@user:~$ uname -a
Linux mrRobot 4.6.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 0):

Kali Linux 2.0 an the rolling release is based on Debian 8.0. VMWare recommends using open-vm-tools for Debian 8.0.

Take a look at the VMWare support article for more information and instructions on how to install open-vm-tools

http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Debian_8.html

Kali Linux 2.0 an the rolling release is based on Debian 8.0. VMWare recommends using open-vm-tools for Debian 8.0.

Take a look at the VMWare support article for more information and instructions on how to install open-vm-tools

http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Debian_8.html

> Open VM Tools is the open source implementation of VMware Tools and
>   consist of a suite of virtualization utilities that improves the
>   functionality, administration, and management of virtual machines on
>   VMware hypervisors. VMware recommends using the Open VM Tools
>   redistributed by the operating system vendors. For additional
>   information, see knowledge base article 2073803, VMware support of
>   open-vm-tools, at http://kb.vmware.com/kb/2073803.

**Install Open VM Tools**

1. Add the following line to the /etc/apt/sources.list file.
   deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
2. Run the commands: 
   $ sudo apt-get update 
   $ sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools
3. Add the following line to the /etc/apt/sources.list file.
   deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
4. Run the commands: 
   $ sudo apt-get update 
   $ sudo apt-get install open-vm-tools

Comment: Okay I did them, but still can't drag&drop files from guest to host or vice versa. I added the output to my question.

Comment: As I already had VMware tools installed on the system it was asking me for replying them so each time i chose "Y", you can see the updated question.

Comment: Does copy/paste work?

Comment: install the VM tools, either VMware or open, often is part of the solution. You may also want to configure the nic card as vmxnet, and the disk controller as paravirtual. The performance gains are significant. No, I do not know the specific steps  for vmware workstation. The open vmware tools are a reengineering of vmware own tools,  and I am not particularly sure they permit  integrated file sharing.